# Tamagawa number of GL(n)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

Weil's conjecture, proved by Kottwitz, states that the Tamagawa number of a semisimple, simply connected algebraic group (over a number field) is 1. For example, $SL(n)$ and induced tori. Is the Tamagawa number of $GL(n)$ known?

Comment: Have you looked at: Tamagawa number of reductive algebraic groups.
Lai, K. F.
Compositio Mathematica,  Volume 41 (1980) no. 2,  p. 153-188?

Comment: I think the answer is just 1. Since $GL_n = SL_n \times \mathbb{G}_m$, $\tau(GL_n)=\tau(SL_n) \tau(\mathbb{G}_m)=1 \times 1 = 1$.

Comment: There is quite a range of literature by now on Tamagawa numbers, including Weil's informal lectures published more formally as a 1982 volume in the PM series *Adeles and Algebraic Groups*.     See especially Chapter III in the long paper by J. Oesterle in Invent. Math. 76 (`984), which confirms that the Tamagawa number of a general linear group is 1 (over a relevant field).     Note by the way that Kottwitz finished off the Tamagawa conjejcture by dealing with a tricky exceptional type.     Most of the literature is aimed at such cases: simply connected semisimple groups over number fields.

Comment: General linear groups are certainly *connected*.     How do you define this notion?